# #Define symbol during web publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, compiler-errors, web-publishing

I have an ASP.NET web application project that references other C# projects. One of those C# projects has a compiler directive that reports an error if a certain symbol is not defined:

```
#if (!FOO || !BAR)

   #error "Define symbol for either FOO or BAR"

#endif
```

When I publish the site, it doesn't define the symbol and, thus, a compiler error results. Is there a way to define a symbol for a referenced project during Visual Studio's publishing process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One work around is to enable the "**Precompile during Publishing**" option.

[image: Screenshot for Visual Studio Publish Web Wizard]